# My array-generation algorithm is broken

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I'm developing aprogram, for which I need an array generation algorithm, however, even though the code **should** work, all the entries are exactly the same, as can be seen by the `System.out.println();` near the end of the code.

I've checked every single part of the rest of my code, and everything runs smoothly, it's just this one algorithm, that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

```
public static ZetaTestTriple[] getTripleArray(int jRange, int kRange, int nRange, MathContext mc){
    ZetaTestTriple[] r = new ZetaTestTriple[(8*(jRange+1)*(kRange)*nRange)];
    int i=0;
    for(int j=0;j<jRange+1;j++){
        for(int k=1;k<kRange;k++){
            for(int n=1;n<nRange+1;n++){
                System.out.println("j="+j+"||k="+k+"||n="+n);
                r[i+0]=new ZetaTestTriple(j,k,n,mc);
                r[i+1]=new ZetaTestTriple(-j,k,n,mc);
                r[i+2]=new ZetaTestTriple(-j,-k,n,mc);
                r[i+3]=new ZetaTestTriple(-j,k,-n,mc);
                r[i+4]=new ZetaTestTriple(j,-k,-n,mc);
                r[i+5]=new ZetaTestTriple(j,k,-n,mc);
                r[i+6]=new ZetaTestTriple(j,-k,n,mc);
                r[i+7]=new ZetaTestTriple(-j,-k,-n,mc);
                i+=8;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("2013="+r[2013].toString());//(-10 * pi^-9)/-10
    System.out.println("3172="+r[3172].toString());//(-10 * pi^-9)/-10
    System.out.println("1283="+r[1283].toString());//(-10 * pi^-9)/-10
    System.out.println("7412="+r[7412].toString());//(-10 * pi^-9)/-10
    //They're all the same...
    return r;
}
```

Edit: Here is the ZetaTestTriple constructor:

```
    private static BigDecimal j,n;
private static int k;
private static MathContext mc;

public ZetaTestTriple(int J, int K, int N, MathContext mathC){
    j=new BigDecimal(J);k=K;n=new BigDecimal(N);
    mc=mathC;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, it looks much better now.

Comment: We need to see the code of the `ZetaTestTriple`-constructor.

Comment: How your algorithm should work? What data are you using to test it? What is ZetaTestTriple?

Comment: Why are the j, k variables static ie same for all ZetaTestTriple's and it is best not to use the same name as a local and a class/instance variable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that your attributes are **static.**

```
private static BigDecimal j,n;
private static int k;
private static MathContext mc;
```

By declaring them as **static**, they are overwritten each time your class is instantiated.